# Escape the hat in HTML?

Tags: html

I am writing some HTML and I can't seem to escape the hat. I tried:

```
<b><code>&Hat;\s*</code></b>
```

and also,

```
<b><code>^\s*</code></b>
```

and neither renders correctly in Firefox. How can I get the indicated markup? The output is supposed to be:

**`^\s*`**

The way it comes out is:

^**\s***

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Tyler is `<b><code>&amp;Hat;\s*</code></b>` what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/b9co00un/3/